# Symfony2 Routing Annotations and JavaScript

Tags: jquery, symfony, annotations, url-routing

I am using annotations for my routing. In my index.twig template I wrote some JQuery like

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable').NestedSortable(
        {
            accept: 'sort',
            noNestingClass: "no-children",
            helperclass: 'helper',
            autoScroll: true,
            onChange: function(serialized) {
            },
            onStop : function(){
                var element_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var parent_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                var prev_sibling_id = $(this).prev().attr("id");
 if(prev_sibling_id=='trash'){
    var data = {PID:element_id};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url:"{{ path('v2_pm_patentgroups_trash') }}",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            document.location.reload(true);
        });
}
else if(parent_id=='sortable'){
     var p_sibling = $(this).prev().attr("value");
     if(p_sibling == null){var p_sibling = 0;}
     var n_sibling = $(this).next().attr("value");
     if(n_sibling == null){var n_sibling = 0;}
     var order = (p_sibling + n_sibling)/2;
     var data = {ID:element_id, ORD:order};
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: data,
         url:"{{ path('v2_pm_patentgroups_sortgroups') }}",
         cache: false
       });
}
```

Now you see there are two ajax callsone is called when a group is trashed and other one is called when the group is sorted.

The group is an li tag which is in my twig file

```
 <li id="{{ portfolio_group.id }}" class="sort group" value={{ portfolio_group.order }}>
    <span class="drag-image groupimage">&nbsp;</span>
    <a class='expand'>{{ portfolio_group.name }}</a>
    <a class="button3" href="{{ path('v2_pm_patentgroups_edit', { 'patentgroupId': portfolio_group.id }) }}" ><span> Edit </span></a> 
            <a class="button3" href="{{ path('v2_pm_patentgroups_delete', { 'patentgroupId': portfolio_group.id }) }}" ><span> Delete </span></a>
    <hr class="separator">
 </li>
```

Can anyone giude me how to give path to url from my inside my JS. I dont want to use routing file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I need to pass data from the controller/view to the javascript I usually set data attributes on the relevant HTML tags. For example, if I need a route for an AJAX request I will write:

```
<a href="#updateTarget" class="ajaxTrigger" data-ajax-route="{{ path('my_ajax_route') }}">click here for ajax</a>
```

and then access it with:

```
$('.ajaxTrigger').on('click', function(){
  $.getJSON($(this).data('ajax-route'), function(response) {
    // do something with response
  });
 });
```

There is also a bundle to do much more sophisticated things with dynamic JS routing https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

**edit:**
For your specific case you could set the route data on the container of the group, the `<ul>`

```
<ul id="portfolioContainer" 
    data-ajax-trash="{{ path('v2_pm_patentgroups_sortgroups') }}" 
    data-ajax-sort="{{ path('v2_pm_patentgroups_sortgroups') }}">
```

and then from your JS file you would refer to those data attributes:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url:$('#portfolioContainer').data('ajax-trash'),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        document.location.reload(true);
    });
```

Comment: The problem is that I have two groups which I can drag like sorting the groups, when i sort any group it should call one method and both the groups are trashable if i trash any of the group it should call another action. think of group as any html tag

Comment: The idea is the same. You would store the generated `path` on *some* tag in your view. Then from your JS file you would access it based on ID. This is just a method to get a generated URL into javascript. If you need more complex JS routes then I would look at the bundle I linked.

Comment: Maybe you can post more of your code and I can give a more detailed explanation.

Comment: edited my answer. also, why are you reloading the whole page after you do the ajax request? It defeats the entire purpose of the ajax :-p

Comment: I am reloading the page because once a group is trashed i replace the two anchor tags of edit and delete by only one restore tag is it possible without reloading the page ? Thanks for the help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13393/discussion-between-mdrollette-and-zoha-ali-khan)

Comment: I tried something like this url:$(element_id).data('ajax-sort') but if i alert it and it says undefined . though the element_id is correct